# Proguard throwing IOException for duplicate zip entry despite only one entry existing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, proguard

I'm using the gradle proguard plugin within intellij (not for an android project), specifying my libraryjars as java home, input jars as jarname.jar, and output jars as jarname.pro.jar. I have a proguard.txt file for configuration, with everything but the Main method keep option excluded. Proguard throws the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/user/src/name/build/libs/jarname.pro.jar] (Can't read [/Users/user/src/name/hci/build/libs/jarname.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [c/a/a/a.class == jarname.jar:com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.class]))

According to this [source from the proguard website](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass), I have duplicate entries in jarname.jar. Manually checking jarname.jar shows no duplicate entries. Where should I be looking to fix this?

Comment: Let me narrow this down a little. Does the proguard gradle plugin take input from anything else besides my reference of -libraryjars and inputjars?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution/hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39584838/1919549

Adapted for your error, add this to build.gradle:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask

def deleteDuplicateJniFiles() {
    def files = fileTree("/Users/user/src/name/hci/build/libs/") {
        include "**/jarname.jar"
    }   
    files.each { it.delete() }
}

tasks.withType(TransformTask) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.doFirst { deleteDuplicateJniFiles() }
}
```

Note this command doesn't actually delete those jars (your duplication error implies they'll be added back in) - only a configuration/exclude block will do that. I have no idea why they're included since, in my project, they were also not duplicated upon inspection of gradle app:dependencies.